# Single quote in FullCalendar javascript scheduler

Tags: javascript, python, fullcalendar

I can't render correctly single quote (') in the title field, even if I have the string with \ escape character.

This is the code:

```
            {{for row in rowseventi:}}
               {
                    title: "{{=row.evento.titolo}}",
                    id: '{{=row.evento.id}}',
                    resourceId: '{{=row.evento.risorsa}}',
                    start: '{{=row.evento.inizio}}',
                    end: '{{=row.evento.fine}}',
                    recurring: '{{=row.evento.ricorrenza}}',
                    // allDay: false,
                    color : '{{=row.evento.colore}}',
                    url: '{{=URL('mostra_evento',args=row.evento.id)}}',
               },
            {{pass}}
```

I tried title: `"{{=row.evento.titolo}}"` and title: `'{{=row.evento.titolo}}'` too (with double or single quote)
This is web2py python code...

row.evento.titolo is

> Dall'Anese Andrea

or

> Dall\'Anese Andrea

but the result is

> Dall&#x27Anese Andrea

Not good!

thank you

Comment: What is this `{{=` syntax? Some other Javascript plugin maybe?

Comment: It's a web2py syntax to embed python instructions into html pages

Comment: Looks like it's doing some UTF encoding. Maybe it's not a normal quote character in your source data

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Well I made my suggestion above, did you check it out?